# Не работает нажатие на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html

При нажатии на кнопку, мне должно вывести число с поля ввода, но когда я нажимаю на нее, ничего не происходит. Как это исправить?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>  
    <script type="text/javascript">         
        var numbers = document.getElementById("num").value;
        function Count_it(){            
            alert(numbers);
        }
    </script>
    <input type = "number" name = "knopka" id = "num">
    <input type = "button" onclick = "Count_it" value = "Обчислити">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Перенести скрипт ниже кнопок, как же он ее найдет, если на момент getElementById их еще нет

Comment: Я делал так, но оно не помогло.

Answer (score 3):

Вы забыли добавить скобки - вызов функции

```
<input type="button" onclick="Count_it()" value ="Обчислити">
```

Также, на момент выполнения скрипта, когда вы получаете значение, у вас ещё нет этого элемента на странице. 
Попробуйте добавить это
`document.getElementById("num").value;` в функцию

```
function Count_it(){            
    var numbers = document.getElementById("num").value;
    alert(numbers);
}
```

Ещё вам необходимо убрать пробелы до и после знака равно (в атрибутах), т.к. браузер может распознавать текст, как разные атрибуты.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @MrSomeone Помимо написанной причины, `var numbers = document.getElementById("num").value;` вне функции срабатывает один раз и записывает в переменную 'numbers' начальное значение инпута (пустую строку). Если дальше значение инпута меняется, от этого переменная не станет менять своё значение. Поэтому нужно обновлять/или объявлять её каждый раз при вызове функции.

Answer (score 1):

1. В тэгах `<script>` никто не пишет, пишут в файлах.js, которые подключают либо в `head` либо в `body`
2. Переменная `numbers` (у тебя) считывает валуе только на инициализации документа, т.е. один раз а не при каждом нажатии
3. Равно с пробелами в `html` не приветствуется, это не яп а язык разметки
4. `onclick` тоже никто уже не использует, ибо [существуют эвенты](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events#ispolzovanie-svoystva-dom-obekta)
5. Алерты желательно не трогать, ибо они для клиентов(пользователей, не разрабов), используй `console.log();`, а вообще вместо стд алертов используют библиотеки, например sweetalerts

Стак здесь: `onclick = "Count_it"`, переделай на `onclick="Count_it()"`

Вот твой код, но с использованием jquery, с ним проще работать ибо меньше букав и проще разбираться

```js
$('#button').click(()=>{
    const value = $('#num').val();
    console.log(value * value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="num">
<input type="button" id="button" value="Рассчитать квандрантб">
```

(ставьте дизлайки за jq, кулсторибоб)